# Plotting a timeseris graph from pandas dataframe using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have the following data in a csv file

```
   SourceID    BSs   hour   Type
    7208       87     11    MAIN
    11060      67     11    MAIN
    3737       88     11    MAIN
    9683       69     11    MAIN
```

I have the following python code.I want to plot a graph with the following specifications.

For each `SourceID` and `Type` I want to plot a graph of `BSs` over time. I would prefer if each `SourceID` and `Type` is a subplot on single plot.I have tried a lot of options using groupby, but can't seem to get it work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

COLLECTION = 'NEW'
DATA = r'C:\Analysis\Test\{}'.format(COLLECTION)
INPUT_FILE = DATA + r'\in.csv'
OUTPUT_FILE = DATA + r'\out.csv'


with open(INPUT_FILE) as fin:
    df = pd.read_csv(INPUT_FILE,
                  usecols=["SourceID", 'hour','BSs','Type'],
                  header=0)

    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far? I don't see any plotting code here.

Comment: @ali_m - I have updated the plotting code.But it is giving some strange plots.

Comment: The `IndexError` was my fault - my code was setting `nrows` to be too small to accommodate all of the plots in cases where `ngrps` is not evenly divisible by `ncols`. This is because I was doing floor division, `ngrps // ncols`, rather than ceiling division, `-(-ngrps // ncols)`. This is now fixed in my answer.

Comment: The warnings are nothing to worry about - they occur whenever there is only a single point to plot, and therefore when the axes are automatically scaled the lower and upper limits are set to the same value. This doesn't matter, since I'm manually setting the axis limits at the end. You could make the warnings go away by either setting the x-axis limits at the time of plotting (e.g. by passing the `xlim=` keyword argument to `rows.plot(..)`), or by preventing the axes from being autoscaled by passing `scalex=False, scaley=False` to `rows.plot()`. I've made the latter change to my answer.

Comment: @ali_m - even after setting `scalex` and `scaley` to false in rows.plot() still  the warning persists.I am not too worried about it at the moment.Please see my comment below about the new error. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not 100% clear to me what sort of plot you actually want, but my guess is that you're looking for something like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# group by SourceID and Type, find out how many unique combinations there are
grps = df.groupby(['SourceID', 'Type'])
ngrps = len(grps)

# make a grid of axes
ncols = int(np.sqrt(ngrps))
nrows = -(-ngrps // ncols)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=True, sharey=True)

# iterate over the groups, plot into each axis
for ii, (idx, rows) in enumerate(grps):
    rows.plot(x='hour', y='BSs', style='-s', ax=ax.flat[ii], legend=False,
              scalex=False, scaley=False)

# hide any unused axes
for aa in ax.flat[ngrps:]:
    aa.set_axis_off()

# set the axis limits
ax.flat[0].set_xlim(df['hour'].min() - 1, df['hour'].max() + 1)
ax.flat[0].set_ylim(df['BSs'].min() - 5, df['BSs'].max() + 5)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want. However If I use your code on my data set I am getting some warnings and errors.Please see details above.

Comment: I am not getting the hour values on x axis in bottom row.` I am getting only a single value of 13 for some reason.

Comment: I have a small hitch issue with this approach. The `value ranges` for `MAIN BSs` and `SUB BSs` and not in the same range. I see that you have set sharey=True. Can we output these two sets of graphs to to different plots?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by *"output these two sets of graphs to to different plots"*. One simple option would be to set `sharey=False` and omit the `set_ylim` line at the end to allow each set of axes to scale its y-axes independently.

Comment: I am using `fig.set_size_inches(200, 100) and fig.savefig('test.png',dpi=100)` to save the plot to a png.What I would like to do is save two plots (`test1.png` and `test2.png`) one for each `Type` (i.e `main` and `sub`)

Comment: I tried `sharey=False` and tried omitting `set_ylim`. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In that case, group by `Type` first, create a figure and subplots within this outer loop, then iterate over `SourceID`s and fill the subplots.